# How do I reload an Angular 6 component when a different component (that is not the parent/child) says to do so

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a header component that allows the user to switch companies. When the user switches a company the data in the dashboard should update to show the new data. This update requires a new API fetch to obtain the data for that newly selected company. How do I trigger a re-initialization of the component that does the fetching and rendering of the new data?

When setActiveCompany() function is invoked I want to refresh the admin component so it can pull the new company data that the UI was switched to.

Currently, the only way I've been able to do this is by forcing a refresh through window.location.href. This is not ideal and not the intended use because this requires the entire app to refresh instead of just the admin component.

Posted below is my service and two relevant components

**company.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getColumns():{header: string, class: string, field: string, tooltipText: string, showTooltip: boolean}[] {
    return [
      {header: "Column 1", class: "med", field: "one", tooltipText: "", showTooltip: false},
      {header: "Column 2", class: "med", field: "two", tooltipText: "", showTooltip: false},
      {header: "Column 3", class: "lg", field: "three", tooltipText: "", showTooltip: true},
      {header: "Column 4", class: "med", field: "four", tooltipText: "", showTooltip: false},
      {header: "Column 5", class: "lg", field: "five", tooltipText: "", showTooltip: true},
      {header: "Column 6", class: "sm", field: "six", tooltipText: "", showTooltip: false}
    ];
  }



  getCompanyData(companyId) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(`${API_URL}/Company/${companyId}`).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);},
        err => {
        console.log("Error retrieving tags", err);
      });
    });
  }


}
```

**admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CompanyService } from '../../services/company.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  companyId: number = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeCompany')).Id;
  companyData: any;
  tableCols: {header: string, class: string, field: string, tooltipText: string, showTooltip: boolean}[];

  constructor(
    private tagService: TagService,
   ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    Promise.all([
      this.companyService.getColumns(),
      this.companyService.getCompanyData(this.companyId),
    ]).then(([tableCols, companyData]) => {
      this.tableCols = tableCols;
      this.companyData = companyData;
    });
  }
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { NavService } from '../../services/nav.service';



@Component({
  providers: [AdminComponent],
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  activeCompanyName: string;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private navService: NavService,
    private router: Router
   ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getToken().then((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.activeCompanyName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeCompany')).Name
      if (!localStorage.getItem('activeCompany')) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeCompany', JSON.stringify(this.user.Companies[0]))
        this.activeCompanyName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeCompany')).Name
      }
    });
  }

  setActiveCompany(company) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeCompany', JSON.stringify(company))
    // This line takes me back to the admin component so I can force a refresh and re-initalize this.companyData
    // I do not want to refresh the page! How do I just refresh the component?
    window.location.href = 'url of admin component';
  }
}
```

Ultimately, this.companyData is the what needs to be refreshed in the admin component template. What's the proper way of doing this starting from the header component? Thank you in advance!

Comment: why do u want to refresh the component instead of pulling new data?

Comment: @Asanka, ultimately what I want to do is pull new data and have the admin component template automatically render this new data. I just wasn't sure how to go about doing this unless I refresh the component? Is there a better way that I'm missing?

Comment: pull all data and just update variables. angular automatically update the dom.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use `Promise` over `Observable`?

Comment: You can see this in action https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtc2jt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) to hold the value within your service, including the initial value from the local storage.

Add this to your Company service:

```
// Holds and pushes the value of the currently active company
private activeCompany$: Subject<any>;

// Computes the active company from local storage and store it as initial value
constructor() {
  const initialActiveCompany = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('activeCompany'));
  this.activeCompany$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(initialActiveCompany);
}

// Returns the observable (read-only) part of this subject
getActiveCompany$(): Observable<any> {
  return this.activeCompany$.asObservable();
}

// Stores the new company value in local storage and pushes it to the subject
setActiveCompany(company: any) {
  window.localStorage.setItem('activeCompany', JSON.stringify(company));
  this.activeCompany$.next(company);
}
```

Then whenever you need to retrieve the active company, use:

```
this.companyService.getActiveCompany$().subscribe((company: any) => { ... });
```

and whenever you need to update it, use the setter.

Note: should ideally replace `any` with a proper type if possible.

Comment: @Smooth Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

### Method 1: Component Hierarchy

One "Angular"-ish way would require the `HeaderComponent` to be a parent of the `AdminComponent`:

**header.component.html:**

```
<div class="my-header">...</div>
<app-admin [activeCompany]="activeCompany"></app-admin>
```

Then you could take advantage of the Angular change detector to trigger `ngOnChanges` in `AdminComponent`, at which point you could trigger a reload of the `getCompanyData` observer. It sounds like this hierarchy might not work well in your app, though.

### Method 2: State Management for Local Storage

The more typical way would be to have a mechanism by which you can listen to LocalStorage changes and trigger a `getCompanyData` call on all relevant changes. This is the same concept used in state management engines like NgRx, Redux, MobX, and others. I did something similar with SessionStorage in an app I built a while ago. I used the [ngx-webstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage) package. It looks like it hasn't been updated in a while so there might be a more up-to-date package, but the idea is still the same.

**admin.component.ts:**

```
...
private companySub: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {
    this.companySub = this.localStorageService.observe('activeCompany')
        .pipe(map(company => JSON.parse(company)))
        .subscribe(company => this.companyService.getCompanyData(company.id));
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.companySub.unsubscribe();
}
...
```

**header.component.ts:**

```
...
setActiveCompany(company) {
    this.localStorageService.store('activeCompany', JSON.stringify(company));
}
...
```

### Method 3: Using a Subject

Finally, a more simple way (for example, if this is the only place you are usnig local storage and don't need a state management engine) would be to manage the value via a shared service:

**company.service.ts:**

```
...
private activeCompany: Subject<Company> = new ReplaySubject(1);
private activeCompany$: this.activeCompany.asObservable()
       .pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

constructor(...) {
    this.activeCompany.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeCompany')));
}

public getActiveCompany$(): Observable<Company> {
    return this.activeCompany$;
}

public setActiveCompany(company: Company): void {
    localStorage.setItem('activeCompany', JSON.stringify(company));
    this.activeCompany.next(company);
}
...
```

Code above isn't tested and may have some issues, especially with more recent changes to RxJS that I haven't worked with yet, but the general idea should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events here but as you are saying that the components are not parent/child then you can use a pubsub event model. 
This npm package allows you to implement that

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-pubsub

If installing an additional package is not a problem for you

Just publish an event "fetchUpdatedData" from component 2 and subscribe this event on component1... On subscription just call the api service and its done. Just read the library docs and you will understand.